# Test app in android phone using command line?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Android Studio is running quite slow in my laptop so Im planning use Android Studio just for building the app structure and use Sublime Text 3 for coding, but I want to test my app in my phone connected via USB using a command within the terminal. ADB maybe? or something else?

Comment: If you are going to use Android Studio rather than the command line for building, it is not clear that avoiding it for install and run will save you much time.  Do pay attention to the difference between triggering the "run" of an app, and starting a jdwp "debug" session - that latter you do want to avoid unless it is specifically needed!

Answer (score 0):

To run your tests from the command line use `am instrument`. For example to run all tests in your package:

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w com.example.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

assuming your application package name is `com.example.foo` and is using `InstrumentationTestRunner`.

To verify your test package is installed, run

```
$ adb shell pm list instrumentation
```

### EDIT

Or, if you just want to run the app once installed

```
$ adb shell am start -n com.example.foo/.MainActivity
```

Comment: If there are actual instrumentation tests - otherwise, merely am start -n com.yourpackage/.whateverActivity or simply start it from the launcher GUI

Comment: Well the OP says `I want to test my app..`, but you are right, it may refer to `run my app`

Answer (score 0):

you can push the apk and install using `adb install`.

Of course, you still need to compile the new APK each time.